# How to substring clob in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to extract the error from the ErrorDescription tag in clob. Here the tag is dynamic its coming with other prefix like "ms1:ErrorDescription" and so on.

Currently I'm using the below query which is fetching only `<ErrorDescription>` values for `<ErrorDescription>` tag; it;s not working for prefix `<ms1:ErrorDescription>` and others

`dbms_lob.substr(error_column dbms_lob.instr(error_column, '</ErrorDescription>')- dbms_lob.instr(error_column, '<ErrorDescription>')- length('<ErrorDescription>'), dbms_lob.instr(error_column, '<ErrorDescription>') + length('<ErrorDescription>') ) as Error_Message`
clob values

`<ErrorDescription>xxxxx</ErrorDescription> <ms1:ErrorDescription>XXXXXX</ms1:ErrorDescription <Ms1:ErrorDescription>XXXXXX</ms1:ErrorDescription> <xml:ErrorDescription>XXXXXX</xml:ErrorDescription>`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer based on comments below -->**

Since you don't want this in a block then try the below

```
 select dbms_lob.substr(error_column , dbms_lob.instr(error_column , 'ErrorDescription', 1, 2) - dbms_lob.instr(error_column , 'ErrorDescription', 1, 1) - length('ErrorDescription') - dbms_lob.instr(error_column , 'ErrorDescription', 1, 1) - 1,
        dbms_lob.instr(error_column, 'ErrorDescription', 1, 1) + length('ErrorDescription') + 1)
 into v_text
 from dual;
```

The key thing that I have done is pass an extra value to instr to tell it what instance of the word to find eg dbms_lob.instr(v_lob, 'ErrorDescription', 1, 2) is looking for the second instance.... this way we don't have to worry about looking for the instance with a backslash meaning we can then ignore the namespace.

**-- end of updated answer**

If this is well formed XML, I would be inclined to convert it from a clob to a XML type and then you can use all the XML standard XML functions to extract the data that you need. Rather than trying to homebrew a substring to get the data you need out of an xml document.

eg

```
Declare
  v_xmlType XMLTYPE;
  v_err_mgs := varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_xmltype := XMLTYPE.createXML(myClob);
  --extract the information
  v_err_msg := l_xmltype.extract('//ErrorDescription');
  -- do more stuff
END;
```

That is at its very basic, you will have to work out the correct xpath to pass for your actual XML. You can then also pass in namespaces to the extract function (what you have called prefix in the question).

Have a look at the below URL for more details from the Oracle documentation, you have not specified a version of oracle so I have assumed 12c, but XML type has been around for a number of versions before this so just find the appropriate version page.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/XMLTYPE.html#GUID-661576F0-FFE6-4338-AD70-B74FE8E9EF56

Comment: I'm not using the plsql block. I just querying in the CLOB column table and getting the error description as query output.   version: Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0. example. There are 100 records in the table. so I'm just trying to pull the error id, error description using SQL query, error id is unique and the error description will be extracting the error from the clob.

Comment: @dkoothan I have updated my answer to show how it can be achieved in a select, doing it this way is messy but should work for your case